# Meteor.wrapAsync is not returning any value with Meteor.Mandrill

Tags: javascript, meteor, mandrill

I'm trying to use the Meteor.Mandrill.send function inside a server-side method.

I want the mandrill method to be synchronous, so I tried this:

```
sendActivationCode: function(liftId, email) {
    check(liftId, String);
    check(email, String);

    var body = 'hello';

    wrappedMandrillSend = Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.Mandrill.send, Meteor.Mandrill);

    var sentMail = wrappedMandrillSend({
      host:           "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
      port:           587,
      to:             email,
      from:           "info@website.meteor.com",
      subject:        'Activation mail',
      html:           body,
      authentication: "LOGIN",
      username:       Meteor.settings.mandrill.username,
      password:       Meteor.settings.mandrill.password
    });

    console.log('sync mail send');

    return sentMail;
  }
```

However `sync mail send` is never displayed. and the function is never returned.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using this package: https://atmospherejs.com/wylio/mandrill (`wylio:mandrill`) you don't need to use wrapAync. Simply use it as normal:

```
sendActivationCode: function(liftId, email) {
    check(liftId, String);
    check(email, String);

    var body = 'hello';

    var sentMail = Meteor.Mandrill.send({
      host:           "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
      port:           587,
      to:             email,
      from:           "info@website.meteor.com",
      subject:        'Activation mail',
      html:           body,
      authentication: "LOGIN",
      username:       Meteor.settings.mandrill.username,
      password:       Meteor.settings.mandrill.password
    });

    console.log('sync mail send');

    return sentMail;
  }
```

The reason it doesn't work is it's trying to make an already synced method sync again. It has no callback hence it will not return.